# How to debug Springboot "Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'... Unable to start embedded Tomcat server on Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: java, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot application with HTTPS enabled on the Digital Ocean droplet. The application ran previously with no issues until a recent restart from the server.

I keep getting "Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'... Unable to start embedded Tomcat server" error.

How can I start to debug this? I tried to capture the output log from the server in a .txt file, and this is the output.

Things I have tried:

- Rolling back to a previous app version
- Updating MySQL version
- Updating server

I'm running:

- Java 11 - jar app
- MySQL v8.0.25 Community Server

```
2021-07-09 04:04:37.224 INFO 9278 --- [ task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] 2021-07-09 04:04:37.238 INFO 9278 --- [ task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2021-07-09 04:04:40.570 INFO 9278 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'],
Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4248b963, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1dc76fa1, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2f508f3c,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@ad9e63e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3abfe845, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@33d53216, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7808f638,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7f08caf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2459319c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@71f0b72e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2650f79]
2021-07-09 04:04:40.607 INFO 9278 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@7be3a9ce, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@37d871c2,
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2c0b4c83, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4893b344, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@3baf6936, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3bfc6a5e,
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@62db0521, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@78525ef9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2d0ecb24,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@285f38f6, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@53a665ad, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@249e0271, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4acb2510]
2021-07-09 04:04:40.610 INFO 9278 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@27b2faa6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@57c47a9e,
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4eed2acf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61d84e08, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@642505c7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4339e0de,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6428591a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@36fc05ff, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@476e8796, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@715d6168]
2021-07-09 04:04:40.779 WARN 9278 --- [ main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop';
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server 2021-07-09 04:04:40.784 INFO 9278 --- [ main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence
unit 'default' 2021-07-09 04:04:40.785 INFO 9278 --- [ main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down' 2021-07-09 04:04:40.786 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL
: alter table contacts drop foreign key FKna8bddygr3l3kq1imghgcskt8 2021-07-09 04:04:40.808 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table leads drop foreign key FK50ynw1akb9fok4ronueu0efpk 2021-07-09 04:04:40.934 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL
: alter table leads drop foreign key FK10u8b7klywjncgkn7xffx7ncu 2021-07-09 04:04:41.033 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table leads_notes drop foreign key FKhpoad9uf9y5lh6nv7iqb06uk2 2021-07-09 04:04:41.065 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL
: alter table leads_notes drop foreign key FK6tw7yuipyu91x1d4csegdumpt 2021-07-09 04:04:41.093 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table submissions drop foreign key FKpy8k2vjp2ax1glqn4tc77f362 2021-07-09 04:04:41.169 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main]
org.hibernate.SQL : alter table submissions drop foreign key FKhwyuy355rlq3e0d1lw5nxywum 2021-07-09 04:04:41.196 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table submissions drop foreign key FKhfixvturyi8nqcvr8qbujkmmd 2021-07-09 04:04:41.227 DEBUG
9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table submissions drop foreign key FKaddc6b566b2j07ndp34akltik 2021-07-09 04:04:41.252 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table users drop foreign key FKin8gn4o1hpiwe6qe4ey7ykwq7 2021-07-09 04:04:41.300
DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table users_roles drop foreign key FKa62j07k5mhgifpp955h37ponj 2021-07-09 04:04:41.331 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : alter table users_roles drop foreign key FK2o0jvgh89lemvvo17cbqvdxaa 2021-07-09
04:04:41.353 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists categories 2021-07-09 04:04:41.361 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists companies 2021-07-09 04:04:41.377 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL
: drop table if exists contacts 2021-07-09 04:04:41.397 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists leads 2021-07-09 04:04:41.446 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists leads_notes 2021-07-09 04:04:41.465 DEBUG
9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists leads_status 2021-07-09 04:04:41.474 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists products 2021-07-09 04:04:41.482 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists
roles 2021-07-09 04:04:41.493 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists submissions 2021-07-09 04:04:41.503 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists submissions_status 2021-07-09 04:04:41.517 DEBUG 9278 ---
[ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists users 2021-07-09 04:04:41.537 DEBUG 9278 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL : drop table if exists users_roles 2021-07-09 04:04:41.560 INFO 9278 --- [ main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting
down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2021-07-09 04:04:41.564 INFO 9278 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated... 2021-07-09 04:04:41.585 INFO 9278 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1
- Shutdown completed. 2021-07-09 04:04:41.599 INFO 9278 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Stopping service [Tomcat] 2021-07-09 04:04:41.636 INFO 9278 --- [ main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : Error starting ApplicationContext.
To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-07-09 04:04:41.652 ERROR 9278 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start
bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at com.maxwelton.investorportal.InvestorPortalBackendApplication.main(InvestorPortalBackendApplication.java:10)
~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[investor-portal-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
~[investor-portal-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[investor-portal-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
~[investor-portal-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)
~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE] ... 22 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE] ... 24 common frames omitted Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1058) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] ... 26 common
frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the [protocols] specified are supported by the SSL engine : [[TSLv1.2]] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.
<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.
  <init>(SSLUtilBase.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.
    <init>(OpenSSLUtil.java:42) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation.getSSLUtil(OpenSSLImplementation.java:36) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:88)
      ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216)
      ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
      ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35] at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1055) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
      ... 28 common frames omitted
```

My DB properties are

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_investor_portal?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=**********
spring.datasource.password=**********

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

#SpringBoot SSL configuration for Digital Ocean
#server.ssl.enabled=true
#server.port=8443
#server.ssl.key-store=/etc/letsencrypt/live/*****
#server.ssl.key-store-password=***********
#server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
#server.ssl.protocol=TLS
#server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TSLv1.2
#server.ssl.ciphers=TSL_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

And my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.maxwelton.investorportal</groupId>
    <artifactId>investor-portal-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>investor-portal-backend</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Backend for MW Investor Portal</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.24</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.maxwelton.investorportal.InvestorPortalBackendApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you need tomcat dependency? Because spring by default have tomcat jar. Can you comment that tomcat dependency and try again?

Comment: There should be some logging produced earlier in startup that shows why Tomcat couldn’t start. Can you share the complete output of the attempt to start your app?

Answer (score 0):

The error says: `None of the [protocols] specified are supported by the SSL engine : [[TSLv1.2]]`

You have a typo in protocol name `TSLv1.2` -> `TLSv1.2`

Also, there is a typo in cipher name, it must be `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`